# Assign value in each row of a pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have written the code shown below:

```
for ind in df.index:
  X=df['POG_X'][ind]
  Y=df['POG_Y'][ind]
  if -960<X<0 and -540<Y<0:
     df.loc[df.index[ind],'Is_ROI']='TRUE'
  else:
     df.loc[df.index[ind],'Is_ROI']='FALSE'
```

So, basically what I am trying to achieve is to assign a 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' value on the 'Is_ROI' column of a pandas df. I can read the X,Y values of each row, but the assignment of TRUE or FALSE, doesn't work as intended. I get either TRUE or FALSE values in the entire 'Is_ROI' column, regardless of the if statement. What I'm missing here?

Comment: How can `960 < X < 0` and  `540 < Y < 0` ever return True?

Comment: Edited it. I forgot the minus signs.

Answer (score 1):

Directly store your conditions in a column:

```
df['Is_ROI']=(df['POG_X'].between(0,-960,inclusive='neither')) & (df['POG_X'].between(0,-540,inclusive='neither'))
```

OR

without `between()`:

```
df['Is_ROI']=(df['POG_X'].gt(-960) & df['POG_X'].lt(0)) & (df['POG_Y'].gt(-540) & df['POG_X'].lt(0))
```

**Note:**

- If you don't need boolean True/False and you need string True/False then just chain `astype(str)` at the end
- If you don't want to include boundaries in comparision then pass `inclusive='neither'` in `between()` method and if you want to include those boundries then remove `inclusive` parameter

Comment: Thanks for this. I edited the post and this solution doesn't work.

Comment: @Phoenix yes because you changed your initial conditions to a whole new condition...that's why

Comment: @Phoenix updated answer kindly see **:)**